# Laravel - Get the Authenticated users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, vue.js

I have a navbar where I try to display some stuff depending if the user is authenticated or not.

So I have a login form, when I axios.post('/login') with the email / password, and I deal with the potential errors.

I have also a method in my UserController to get the authenticated user (if there is one) via Auth::user() like the docs says, but this methods always returns an empty object ...

```
public function getUser() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    Log::info($user);
    return $user;
}
```

This methods always returns me a `[2018-06-17 16:29:26] local.INFO:`

But the stranger things (like the TV show) is where I try to go on my '/admin' routes, my middleware use also the 'Auth::user()' to determines if the user's role is 'user' or 'admin', that 'Auth::user()' methods returns me well the user ...

I am stuck ... 
Please, if someone has experienced the same issue, let me know how to solve it, or if someone want to see more code, let me know as well I'll be glad to show you more proof.

Thanks,

Comment: Show your route declaration, is that protected by `web` middleware group?

Comment: Are you using Auth::user() before $this->attemptLogin($request) or inside if statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getUser() {
    $user = Auth::user()->name;    
    return $user;
}
```

Use `Auth::user()->name;` to return your user name on navbar.

Comment: Hummm what my Log::info(Auth::user()) are working on my middleware function tho ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide further info to `Log::info()`, Something like the name or id  of the `$user->name`, `$user->id`.

Further more you can use that id, Search with it and get the info of the user.
You should have a proper pattern for the log, By pattern i means proper logging. Passing the whole object `$user` will not work.

Comment: I tried, but my Auth::user() is empty so i can’t access to anything, i just don’t know why that object is empty. I log in my app, if I try to activite my authAdmin middleware I see my user into my Log::info(Auth::user) but when I call a method from my controllers through axios when my component is mounted I have nothing in here

Answer (score 0):

Hello you must use  this syntax on laravel version 8 and more

```
auth('api')->user()->id
```

api will be used when you have an api if you are on a web version you will use

```
 auth('web')->user()->id
```